# Number of points which satisfy the tangency condition

Tags: functions

The number of points in the rectangle 
{(x,y) $-10 \leq x \leq 10$ and $ -3\leq y \leq 3$

which lie on the curve $y^2 = x+sinx$and at the which the tangent to the curve is parallel to the x-axis, is 
a.) 0 
b.) 2
c.)4
d.)8

My attempt - I tried to solve the equation by differentiating and putting the slope to zero 
However I got four possible option choices -3$\pi$ , -$\pi$ , $\pi$ , $3\pi$.

Please tell me if I am doing something wrong or forgetting to eliminate some options checking against the constraint.

Comment: Answer: b) points $(\pi,\pm\sqrt{\pi})$. Others lie outside the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the implicit derivative you get
$$
2yy' = 1 + \cos x
$$
and you need the tangent to be parallel to the $x$-axis, i.e. $y' = 0$, so you get $\cos x = -1$, which results in the solutions you posted, $x \in \{\pm \pi, \pm 3\pi\}$.

Note that to find $y$ you plug them back into the original equation
$$
y^2 = x + \sin x
$$
and note that $\sin x = 0$ for all your solutions, and since we are assuming real $y$, you are restricted to $x > 0$, leaving the solutions
$$
\left(\pi, \pm \sqrt{\pi} \right), \left(3\pi, \pm \sqrt{3\pi} \right).
$$

Since $\sqrt{3\pi} > \sqrt{3 \cdot 3} = 3$, only the solutions $\left(\pi, \pm \sqrt{\pi} \right)$ satisfy all constraints.

Comment: OP already did this.

Comment: @EugenCovaci thanks, updated

Comment: Since when was $\sqrt{3\pi}\le3$?

Comment: @almagest i was hoping the OP can do this himself, but did edit the answer for clarity.

Comment: @gt6989b Ah, sorry. I failed to grasp that.